# Analog sensors (photo resistor and moisture sensor) do not work in combination with wifi function of ESP32

Tags: c, wifi, esp32, arduino-ide

i'm trying to build an sensor service where a couple of sensors (DHT22, photo resistor and  moisture sensor and an extra temperature sensor) are connected to an esp wroom 32. The wiring is correct. And now that i have connected all my sensors to my esp32, i want to send my data to an extra server, where i already succeeded. I can send my data with an post request but only data from my digital sensors.

Now my Problem: My photo resistor and  moisture sensor are analog sensors not like the dht22 and if i try to connect to my wifi and get data from my analog sensors, only my analog sensors are sending false/static/default data.

My ESP is connected to my PC so i don't know if my power supply can be the problem. My Sketch is also not that big and "only" takes (72%) of my storage space. My analog sensors are connected to D2 and D4 Pin.

Has anybody a suggestion what i can do, to fix my problem. I know that every sensor works and also all together just without the wifi/post/get request function.

This is my great code. with great german and english comments. (i hope you get my irony).

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h> 
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <ESPAsyncWebSrv.h> 
#include "DHT.h"

#define DHTPIN 21 
#define KY001_Signal_PIN 5
#define DHTTYPE DHT22 


// Bibliotheken werden konfiguriert
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);
OneWire oneWire(KY001_Signal_PIN);          
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);    

int sensorPin = 4;  //fotowiderstand der nicht geht 
 int soilMoistPin = 2;  // bodenfeuchte

const int soilMoistLevelLow = 533;    //Dieser Wert soll von euch entsprechend angepasst werden
const int soilMoistLevelHigh = 258;   //Dieser Wert soll von euch entsprechend angepasst werden


const size_t bufferSize = JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(5); // hier wird die anzahl der json felder definiert

const char* ssid = "ssid";
const char* password = "password";

AsyncWebServer server(80);

// the following variables are unsigned longs because the time, measured in
// milliseconds, will quickly become a bigger number than can be stored in an int.
unsigned long lastTime = 5000;
// Set timer to 30 seconds
unsigned long timerDelay = 30000;

void setup() {
  
  Serial.begin(115200);
     // Sensor intialisierung
  wifiSetup();
  dht.begin();
  sensors.begin(); 
  pinMode(soilMoistPin, INPUT);
  getRequestFunc(); 
    
}
void wifiSetup(){
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.println("Connecting");
  while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(300);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Connected to WiFi network with IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println(WiFi.status());
  
 
  Serial.println("Timer set to 5 seconds (timerDelay variable), it will take 5 seconds before publishing the first reading.");
}

float getMoisture(){
  int soilMoist = analogRead(soilMoistPin);
  Serial.print("Analog Value: ");
  Serial.print(soilMoist);
  // Auswertung der Bodenfeuchtigkeit in Prozent
  int percentSoilMoist = map(soilMoist, soilMoistLevelHigh, soilMoistLevelLow, 100, 0);
  Serial.print("\t"); 
  Serial.print(percentSoilMoist);
  Serial.println(" %");
  return percentSoilMoist;
}

float getTemperature(){
    float temperature;
    sensors.requestTemperatures();
    // ... und die gemessene Temperatur wird ausgeben
    temperature = sensors.getTempCByIndex(0);
    Serial.print("Temperatur: ");
    Serial.print(sensors.getTempCByIndex(0));
    Serial.println(" °C");
    return temperature;

}

void getDHTData(){
   delay(2000);

  // Reading temperature or humidity takes about 250 milliseconds!
  // Sensor readings may also be up to 2 seconds 'old' (its a very slow sensor)
  float h = dht.readHumidity();
  // Read temperature as Celsius (the default)
  float t = dht.readTemperature();
  // Read temperature as Fahrenheit (isFahrenheit = true)
  float f = dht.readTemperature(true);

  // Check if any reads failed and exit early (to try again).
  if (isnan(h) || isnan(t) || isnan(f)) {
    Serial.println(F("Failed to read from DHT sensor!"));
    return;
  }

  // Compute heat index in Fahrenheit (the default)
  float hif = dht.computeHeatIndex(f, h);
  // Compute heat index in Celsius (isFahreheit = false)
  float hic = dht.computeHeatIndex(t, h, false);

  Serial.print(F("Humidity: "));
  Serial.print(h);
  Serial.print(F("%  Temperature: "));
  Serial.print(t);
  Serial.print(F("°C "));
  Serial.print(f);
  Serial.print(F("°F  Heat index: "));
  Serial.print(hic);
  Serial.print(F("°C "));
  Serial.print(hif);
  Serial.println(F("°F"));
}

float getFotowiderstand(){
    // Aktueller Spannungswert wird gemessen...
    float rawValue = analogRead(sensorPin);
    float voltage = ((4095 - rawValue) / 4095) * 100;

    // Helligkeit in Prozent = ((Maximalwert - Aktuelle Spannung) / Maximalwert) * 100
         
    // float resitance = 10000 * ( voltage / ( 5000.0 - voltage) );
         
    // ... und hier auf die serielle Schnittstelle ausgegeben
    Serial.print("Aktuelle Helligkeit:"); Serial.print(voltage); Serial.print(" %");
    Serial.print("Eigentliche Spannung:"); Serial.print(rawValue); Serial.println("mV");
    Serial.println("---------------------------------------");

    return voltage;
 

}

//  String getMac(){
//  uint8_t mac[6];
//   WiFi.macAddress(mac);

//   // Convert MAC address to string
//   char macStr[18];
//   sprintf(macStr, "%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X", mac[0], mac[1], mac[2], mac[3], mac[4], mac[5]);

//   // Print the MAC address
//   Serial.print("MAC Address: ");
//   Serial.println(macStr);
//   return macStr;

// }

void getRequestFunc(){
  server.on("/temperature", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
    // Request handling
    float temperature = getTemperature();
    String temperatureString = String(temperature, 2);  // Format the temperature with 2 decimal places
    request->send(200, "text/plain", temperatureString);
    postFunction();
    
  });
  // Start the server
  
  server.begin();
}

void postFunction(){
  // WiFiClient client;
   HTTPClient http;
    
      http.begin("https://sensor-backend-iwillnotsharethat/sensor/post");

      http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

      int httpResponseCode = http.POST(mapToJson());

     if(httpResponseCode>0){
  
         String response = http.getString();  //Get the response to the request
  
          Serial.println(httpResponseCode);   //Print return code
          Serial.println(response);           //Print request answer
  
      } 
    else{
  
    Serial.print("Error on sending POST: ");
    Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
    }
      http.end();
    }
   
   String mapToJson(){
    
    StaticJsonDocument<bufferSize> jsonDocument;
    float fotowiderstand = getFotowiderstand();
    jsonDocument["temperature"] = dht.readTemperature();
    jsonDocument["sensorId"] = "100";
    jsonDocument["humidity"] =  dht.readHumidity();
    jsonDocument["light"] =  fotowiderstand;
    jsonDocument["moisture"] = getMoisture();

    String jsonString;
    serializeJson(jsonDocument, jsonString);

    Serial.println(jsonString);
    return jsonString;
   }


void loop() {
checkIfAllSensorsAlive();
  //Send an HTTP POST request every 30 seconds minutes
  if ((millis() - lastTime) > timerDelay) {
    //Check WiFi connection status
    if(WiFi.status()== WL_CONNECTED){
      postFunction();
     
  }
   else {
      Serial.println("WiFi Disconnected");
    }
    lastTime = millis();
  }
delay(5000);
}

void checkIfAllSensorsAlive(){
  getMoisture();
  getDHTData();
  getFotowiderstand();
  getTemperature();
}`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ADC2 (GPIOs 0, 2, 4, 12 - 15 and 25 - 27) is used by WiFi, unfortunately you can't use it at the same time.

Solution: use ADC1 (GPIOs 32 - 39).

https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/v4.2/esp32/api-reference/peripherals/adc.html